# Is there a way to check the value of the loop parameter from ActionScript?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, actionscript

There are a number of parameters that can be added to `object` and `embed` tags to embed flash videos. Most are listed [here](http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/127/tn_12701.html). Some of them can be accessed/changed programmatically via ActionScript (e.g. `<param name="scale">` can be accessed via `stage.scaleMode`).

Can the value for the `loop` parameter be accessed/changed?

Edit to add: *I know about flashvars, that's not what I'm asking.*

Comment: I could be wrong but I'm 90% sure that AS doesn't have a loop equivalent - simply because it doesn't need one. What are you trying to accomplish, maybe I can point you in the right direction.

Comment: I'm trying to figure out which parameters *can* be accessed from AS to keep my programs [DRY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DRY). Also, I'd like to be able to use flash's built in parameters in a few various programs. I'm 90% sure that they can't be accessed directly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The general net consensus is that no, you can not access parameters other than flashvars/movie from inside Flash.

However, you can access the parameters, in some browsers at least, from JavaScript - and of course you can interface between Flash and JavaScript using an external.

Perhaps a javascript routine along the lines of:

```
function getParam(paramName) {
    return $('#flashid param[name=' + paramName + ']').val();
}
```

Along with a method in Flash:

```
import flash.external.ExternalInterface;

function getParam(paramName:String):String {
    return String(ExternalInterface.call("getParam", paramName));
}
```

Obviously ensuring script access is enabled on the SWF and the object/embed.

Comment: @gthmb Well I've not tested it, but the principle seems sound to me.  The JS bit works.  Quite typical of Flash not to have direct access to its own configuration, I'm still not sure that is true, seems too stupid.  But then this is Flash...

Answer (score 1):

"Can the value for the `loop` parameter be accessed/changed (via ActionScript)?"
*Short answer:* **Don't bother.**

*Long answer:*

@Orbling's answer relies on checking via JavaScript, which could theoretically be in an inconsistent state if the parameter was added or removed from when the embedded flash video was added.

I thought up an indirect way to check if the play or loop parameters were set. The parameters can only be detected if there are two or more frames in the root video.

**First Frame**

```
if (temp.loadParams.playParam)
{
  temp.loadParams.loopParam = true;
  //uses external interface to log to the console (essentially the same as trace)
  temp.say('temp: looped');
  stop();
}
```

**Second Frame**

```
if (!temp.loadParams.playParam)
{
  temp.loadParams.playParam = true;
  temp.say('temp: played');
}
```

`temp` is the document class name, and loadParams is just a static object to store the param states. If the `play` param is true, the video will go to frame 2, which sets the `playParam` value. If the `loop` param is true, the video will then go back to frame 1, which sets the `loopParam` value.

If `play` is false, `loop` could still be detected using some fancy footwork with the `Event.ENTER_FRAME` but at this point, it's ridiculous to continue checking values for a parameter that can simply be overridden by `play();` or `stop();` in the first or last frame.

Comment: A sensible idea, though you would not know if loop was set until it looped.

Comment: @Orbling exactly, which is why I awarded you the bounty.

Comment: Aye, most appreciated.  My answer is far from ideal, but the only method I could fathom for getting the data.  The inconsistency flaw may be avoidable, by detecting browser and knowing how to access the parameter post-initialisation.  If the default right-click menu is enabled, loop can be changed I believe, and that is probably internal, so I would only trust such parameters early on.