# What parameters can be used when embedding a flash video, and how can they be accessed via ActionScript?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, actionscript, parameters

No matter whether you embed a flash video using [Flash Satay](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/flashsatay), swfobject, or some other method, there are a number of parameters that can be passed to the embedded video.

I'd like this to be a community wiki for the following questions:

- What parameters can be used to embed a flash video?
- How can the parameters be accessed via ActionScript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adobe has an object embedding reference that lists [some of the possible parameters](http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/127/tn_12701.html). Notably missing is the `allowFullScreen` parameter.

The following assumes "[Satay Method](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/flashsatay)":

```
<object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="path/to/file.swf">
 <param name="movie" value="path/to/file.swf" />
</object>
```

## What parameters can be used to embed a flash video?

```
      Parameter       |    Type     |  How
=======================================================
align                 | <param> tag | stage.alignα
allowFullScreen       | <param> tag | ---
base                  | <param> tag | ---
bgcolor               | <param> tag | ---
classid               | attribute   | ---
codebase              | attribute   | ---
data                  | attribute   | ---
flashvars             | <param> tag | stage.loaderInfo.parameters or documentObject.loaderInfo.parameters
fullScreenAspectRatio | <param> tag | ---
height                | attribute   | stage.stageHeight†
id                    | attribute   | ExternalInterface.objectID‡
loop                  | <param> tag | not directly accessible◊
menu                  | <param> tag | stage.showDefaultContextMenu
movie                 | <param> tag | ---
name                  | attribute   | ExternalInterface.objectID‡
play                  | <param> tag | not directly accessible◊
quality               | <param> tag | stage.quality
salign                | <param> tag | stage.alignα
scale                 | <param> tag | stage.scaleMode
seamlesstabbing       | <param> tag | ---
swliveconnect         | <param> tag | ---
width                 | attribute   | stage.stageWidth†
wmode                 | <param> tag | ---
```

† only if `scale` is set to `no_scale`
‡ for cross-browser compatibility both the `id` and `name` attributes must be present, and set to the same value.
◊ see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4270555/497418) on how to indirectly access the value.
α NOTE: not sure whether `align`, `salign` or both are available via `stage.align`

Comment: You're missing [allowscriptaccess](https://helpx.adobe.com/flash/kb/control-access-scripts-host-web.html)

Comment: Also [allownetworking](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ActionScript/3.0_ProgrammingAS3/WS1EFE2EDA-026D-4d14-864E-79DFD56F87C6.html#WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7c5b)

Comment: @BAM5, this is a community wiki post for a reason, go ahead and add the relevant entries.

Comment: Oh neato, I'm not totally familiar with stackoverflow, thanks for the info.